# getting "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals" error using cat

Tags: matlab, concatenation

I have two structures `x1` and `y1` both of sizes `680*1024*17`.

When I am doing `Y = cat(3,x1,y1)`, I get this error:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

Anyone to help please?

Comment: I don't get any error like that, try this and tell if you are still getting an error: `a=randi([-4 4],[10 11 12]);
b=randi([-4 4],[10 11 12]);
c=cat(3,a,b);`

Comment: thanks for your help !! It was my big mistake .. I was somewhere using cat as a variable and then I was using it for concatenation. Again, my bad.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 0):

As you describe the function `cat` was accidentally overloaded by a variable.